# Excel into CSV VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble saving one sheet from my workbook into a CSV file. I have 18 sheets in the one workbook. Every time I run the macro, it saves a different sheet. I also need it so the display alerts do not pop up. I am a beginner to VBA and running macros, so any help would be appreciated.

```
   Sub csvfile()
 '
 ' csvfile Macro
 '

 '

   ChDir "C:\Users\RM\Documents"
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\RM\Documents\Working_Program\PSSE_Export_Data.csv", FileFormat:= _
    xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False





End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` needs to go before the `.SaveAs`, not after.

Comment: I believe `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` will save the current active sheet. So make sure you've activated the sheet to save first.

Comment: You can start by putting `DisplayAlerts = False` **before** the operation that might display the alerts instead of **after**. That's common sense. You can't shut the barn door after the horse has run off and expect it to magically put the horse back in the stall, can you?

Comment: A CSV file is a plain text file, so it cannot hold data of more than one sheet. Without testing, I would assume that Excel saves only the sheet that is currently visible when saving as CSV

Comment: Have you looked into copying the active sheet to a new workbook, then saving the new workbook as CSV, as CSV will only have one, unformatted sheet?  This would allowyou to run the macro once, for all sheets.

Comment: `DisplayAlerts = False `, after implementing before the SaveAs function, it still saves the wrong sheet. Any other suggestions

Comment: Any other suggestions? Start by reading what people are writing. Moving DisplayAlerts makes it so *the display alerts dont pop up*. Why would you think it would do anything else than that? It doesn't have anything to do with saving the sheets.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I used your information but my next problem was saving a particular sheet. That is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, Just specify the sheet that you want to save in place of "Sheet1"

```
Sub csvfile()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Users\RM\Documents\Working_Program\PSSE_Export_Data.csv", FileFormat:= _
xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: actually I receieved an error, runtime error. and when I debugged it, this was highlighted: `ws.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Users\RM\Documents\Working_Program\PSSE_Export_Data.csv", FileFormat:= _
xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False`

Comment: never mind, I saved it under wrong directory. Also, I had a question about running a macro while that current CSV is open. I always receive an error. Is there a way to run that program while the CSV file is open. Just curious. The macro code works only when the CSV file you are creating is not open. Let's say I have to update information, instead of creating a new CSV file, is there a way to save that current one.

Comment: If the file is open you will always receive a runtime error. The only thing you could really do is to save it as another file name if you receive that particular runtime error. What would be the need for this functionality out of curiosity?... just wondering if there are any other solutions I could suggest

Comment: My goal is to rewrite and replace the csv file. If for example, numbers were to change on that sheet. This VBA would automatically replace and save new data. Instead of me consistently having to save it my self, and having the two messages that pop when saving a CSV file. If there is a more efficient way, I am all ears.

Comment: Hi Mark, Just a suggestion and don't know if it will suit your needs, but it sounds like you are having trouble as people can be using the csv file whilst you are trying to edit/ resave the file. You could look to programmatically set the csv file to read only, and then people can only read the data however you can save over it at your will.

Comment: Using a VBA how would I do that. So lets say I have an excel sheet named "Export_Data" and I want to convert that one sheet into a CSV file. Let's say the data has 5 columns, and the format stays the same, all I do now is change data for 2 of those columns. If I do read only, are u saying, it will save the new data and it can't be changed while on the CSV file.